# Problema con linux y la contraseña

Tags: linux, ubuntu

tengo un problema con mi contraseña. Quiero instalar algo desde la terminal, en este caso quiero instalar Visual Studio Code pero al poner `"sudo dpkg -i code_1.29.1-1542309157_amd64.deb"` me pide mi contraseña al escribir no me aparece nada (intenté escribiendo de igual forma completa pero aun así no me entra por que dije "tal vez es para que alguien a tu alrededor no vea la contraseña"), al apretar enter me deja escribir en un breve periodo de 1 segundo la contraseña, aun así no me entra, realmente quiero instalar programas en mi pc y no puedo

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar capturas terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que eres (muy) nuevo en Linux. Cuando se introduce una contraseña desde una terminal en Linux NUNCA aparecen caracteres que se introducen. Tampoco aparecen caracteres enmascarados '*'. Ese segundo en el que crees que sí se puede teclear la contraseña es el momento en el que sistema esta comprobando la contraseña dada antes de pulsar enter.

Para instalar ese paquete, desde una terminal simplemente hay que hacer

```
$ sudo dpkg -i nombredepaquete.deb
[sudo] contraseña para tunombredeusuario:       <- Teclea tu contraseña y pulsa enter aunque no aparezca nada
```

Otra cosa, para instalar Visual Studio Code, Microsoft provee un repositorio que mantiene actualizado. Es decir, que si instalas ese .deb instalarás Visual Studio Code, pero no se actualizará. Para mantener actualizado Visual Studio Code en Ubuntu deberías, añadir el repo e instalar siguiendo [las instrucciones](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) que dan en su web:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code # or code-insiders
```

De esta forma cada vez que se lance una nueva versión el sistema lo detectará informándote de que hay actualizaciones disponibles.

Answer (score 0):

cuando dices no me entra, es que te pone contraseña inválida o por que?

Por otro lado en linux cuando vas a poner contraseñas nunca se marca nada, ni puntos, ni espacios ni nada.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas ver cuantos caracteres presionas al poner la contraseña (verás asteriscos):

```
sudo visudo
```

y donde veas:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

debes escribir al final de la línea:

```
Defaults        env_reset,pwfeedback
```